# How to use Prototypes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

whats wrong with my below code? Im getting error Object # has no method 'subtract'.

```
function result() {

}
result.prototype.add = function (a,b) {
var sub = this.subtract(a,b);
}
result.prototype.subtract = function (a,b) {
return a-b;
}

module.exports = result;
```

Comment: You need to also share the code that's actually causing the error

Comment: i have posted the code above which is causing error.

Comment: That code doesn't fire any error (after you define module as a dumb object to support last line). I guess the error is fired in some other part of your code that you haven't posted

Comment: @user87267867: You need to show us how you create a `result` instance and how you invoke the `add` method (which you seem to do wrong). Read on the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @Bergi result.prototype = new Validator();

function result() {
}

result.prototype.validate = function (a,b) {
if ((a !=0) && (b !=0)) {
        return this.add(a,b);

    }

}

Comment: Thanks, using [`new Validator` for the prototype might be your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here). Still you didn't show us *how your create a `result` **instance** and how you invoke the `add` method*!

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess would be to call a `new` function.

```
function result() {

}
result.prototype.add = function (a,b) {
   var sub = this.subtract(a,b);
}
result.prototype.subtract = function (a,b) {
   return a-b;
}

module.exports = new result();
```

Comment: Well, then it's probably the way you're calling the function that's the problem, how are you using this?